# How do I iterate over a MIDIPacketList with RubyMotion?

Tags: objective-c, coremidi, rubymotion

How would I translate [this PGMidi example code](https://github.com/petegoodliffe/PGMidi/blob/master/Sources/UI/MidiMonitorViewController.mm#L158-172) to RubyMotion? [The documentation the MIDIPacketList](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CACoreMIDIRef/MIDIServices/CompositePage.html#//apple_ref/c/tag/MIDIPacketList) mentions special caveats and I'm not sure how to account for them in RubyMotion. Example:

> Note that the packets in the list, while defined as an array, may not be accessed as an array, since they are variable-length.

Here's the example, and further down, as far as I've gotten in the translation:

```
- (void) midiSource:(PGMidiSource*)midi midiReceived:(const MIDIPacketList *)packetList
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addString:)
                           withObject:@"MIDI received:"
                        waitUntilDone:NO];

    const MIDIPacket *packet = &packetList->packet[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < packetList->numPackets; ++i)
    {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addString:)
                               withObject:StringFromPacket(packet)
                            waitUntilDone:NO];
        packet = MIDIPacketNext(packet);
    }
}
```

I know I'm losing the pointer referencing/dereferencing with the 'packet' local var and 'packetList', but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to correct it:

```
def midiSource(midi, midiReceived:packetList)
  self.performSelectorOnMainThread('addString',
                   withObject:'MIDI received:',
                   waitUntilDone:false)

  packet = packetList.packet[0]
  i = 0
  while i < packetList.numPackets
    i += 1

    self.performSelectorOnMainThread('addString',
                                     withObject:stringFromPacket(packet),
                                     waitUntilDone:false)
    packet = MIDIPacketNext(packet)
  end
end
```

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: What errors are you getting? One observation your add string selector should most likely have colons on the end e.g. `addString:`

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for the reply! I've decided to take a break from RubyMotion and dig into a Objective-C a bit further. The learning curve for RubyMotion proved unpleasantly steep without a better grounding in Objective-C. I'll update this thread once I get my feet under me.

Answer (score 0):

If it's handling pointers you're looking for, RubyMotion provides the `Pointer` class. http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/guides/runtime/#_pointers

Comment: Thanks for link! I ended up submitting a support request and learned that there's a bug in the RubyMotion compiler. The support agent [filed a bug report](http://hipbyte.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/issue/RM-33#comment=74-760) and while it has seen some activity, we're 10 months on and still no resolution. Certainly giving me pause about writing a MIDI app with RubyMotion.